# Check URL when page is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to change website pages with hashtag when site is loading.
For example when in browser address bar type:

```
http://example.com/#about
```

about page open in browser.
I use this:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(e){
    var anchor = document.location.hash;
    nextPage(anchor);
});
```

for change page when user press on menu button and it works well, but I need this check happen in first of load website too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trigger an event immediately, use [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

```
$('selector').on('event', function(e) { ... }).trigger('event');
```

So you would do:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(e){
    var anchor = document.location.hash;
    nextPage(anchor);
}).trigger('hashchange');
```